# Почему в Select нет имени переменной?

Tags: c#, linq

Не совсем понятно было как назвать этот вопрос, так что буду признателен если поправят тему.

Есть функция для получения из массива только непустых строк.

```
public static int[] ParseNumbers(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    return lines
        .Where(x => x != "")
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Почему в `Select(int.Parse)` а не `Selext(x=>x)`? Хотя этот код работает без проблем, не совсем понятно как оно работает.

Comment: `Select(x=>x)` вернет `IEnumerable<string>` и после вызова `ToArray` результатом будет массив строк, а функции нужно вернуть массив целых чисел, поэтому к каждому элементу применяется функция `int.Parse`

Comment: Вы всегда можете написать полную форму, если эта вас сбивает с толку. `x => int.Parse(x)` и всё.

Comment: @Monk, это не полная форма :-) это функция внутри которой вызывается функция.

Comment: @Grundy оно компилится в разные инструкции?

Comment: @Monk, зависит от компилятора, может и в одни, может в разные

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int.Parse` называется группой методов(группа может состоять как из одного метода, так и из нескольких, в случае наличия перегруженных версий). Группа методов может быть сконвертирована(согласно 6.6 спецификации C#) в совместимый делегат. 
Т.к. `Select` принимает `Func<Result, Arg>`, а `int.Parse`  имеет следующую сигнатуру: `static int Parse(string s)`, то она(группа) конвертируется в делегат `Func<int, string>` который и вызывается внутри `Select`

Comment: ох как все сложно(

Comment: @Radzhab, наоборот, это всё очень просто. Если имели дело с C++, то это чем-то похоже на указатели на функции.